# Take snapshot of entity at certain time in another table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am making an e-commerce application

I have an Abstract entity in which all entities extends it

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractEntity<?>>
{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created;

....
)
```

I have AddressEntity

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
public class Address extends AbstractEntity<Address>
{
    private String name;
    private String lineOne;
    private String lineTwo;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String contactName;

    @OneToOne
    private City city;
    @JsonView(Views.Admin.class)
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
....
```

And i Have OrderEnity class

```
@Entity
public class OrderEntity extends AbstractEntity<OrderEntity>
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("orderEntity")
    private List<LineItem> lineItems = new ArrayList<LineItem>();

    private Address address

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User placedBy;
```

Required Business:
As a user I ordered an order on a my current address but if i changed my address I want the address persisted in OrderEntity Table the same of the old address, In other language I want address persisted in the OrderEntity table to be unchangeable even if the address of the user changed

Comment: Whenever the user changes her address you can create an new one instead of updating the exisiting one.

Comment: I think this is a bad practice you unnecessarily filling the database with records. Every User will update his address for at least two times

Comment: Maybe Envers would work better in your case https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

Answer (score 0):

You are really having two entities here: `Address` which is the address of a person and `OrderAddress` which is the address of an order.

When creating the `Order` you should create an `OrderAddress` from the `Address` of the person doing the ordering.

You could use any mapping tool to copy over the attributes or just code it by hand, which should be a no brainer.

Comment: Of course i can do that but i am asking if there is a shortcut without doing another entity which is OrderAddress. Something like a snapshot of a record